# Can we query document contents in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is that possible to query document contents in Azure Cosmos DB?
How?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cosmos DB supports querying documents using a familiar SQL (Structured Query Language) like grammar over hierarchical JSON documents without requiring explicit schema or creation of secondary indexes.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-reference) provides documentation for the SQL query language syntax, which is compatible with SQL API accounts.

For a walkthrough of example SQL queries, see [SQL queries in Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query).

Comment: But if I want to search for specific keyword in the word document using this SQL query for Cosmos db documents? is that possible?